Project language appears incorrect on github
I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project. On GitHub, project language appears as JavaScript. I think that's because library files on my project makes it wrong. I tried changing .gitattribute and .gitignore but still the same.
I added these lines:
.gitignore:
wwwroot/lib/

.gitattribute:
*.cs linguist-language=C#


Have you committed the library files?

Yes I did. Should I have commited after adding them to .gitignore?

If you wish to ignore the files they should not be committed. Please see How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?

I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one suggested by evolutionxbox. This question is about GitHub, not Git.

@MarkSeemann I think I understand your reasoning, but I still (respectfully) disagree. GitHub is detecting the incorrect language because ignored library files were tracked. Removing these library files should correct GitHub's project language detection

As far as I know, GitHub infers the project language from the files in the repository. If you've used a wizard to generate an empty ASP.NET MVC site, it usually comes with a lot of javascript files for the frontend. If so, GitHub's inference is technically correct.
My experience with GitHub is that once you start adding more C# code files, the site will pick up on that and over time detect that more than one language is being used in the code base. Here's an old repo of mine that exhibits that property: https://github.com/ploeh/Booking. 86.4% JavaScript and 13.6% C#, even though, as far as I recall, I never wrote any JavaScript in that repo.
I'm not aware that there's any way you can change the inference that GitHub makes, but it's also just purely informational. It has no impact on your code base.

No I created project manually but I have lots of library files. I think that's the reason. And yes I know it has no impact on my code base but it just annoys me.
